# How to use Multipart Volley Request.?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to upload video in a multipart volley request. Just want to know, how to use and how to add multipart params in that.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this its a complete working code of sending video or large file to server via multapart.

```
public static Boolean SendPostToServer(FBPost postData, Context context, String videoPath) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(context.getString(R.string.url_service_post));
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if(!videoPath.isEmpty()){

            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", filebodyVideo);
        }
        reqEntity.addPart("userId", new StringBody(postData.userId));
        reqEntity.addPart("postText", new StringBody(postData.postText));
        if(postData.postId != null && postData.postId.length() > 0) {
            reqEntity.addPart("postId", new StringBody(postData.postId));
        }
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }

        Log.e("Response: ", s.toString());
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. But are you sure that it will not give out of memory error for large files.(eg:20Mb to 50Mb).?

Comment: No it will send your data in chunks, and will not give out of memory error

Comment: Have you included httpmime.jar file in your project?

Comment: If not download this and copy in your project libs folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35720/discussion-between-muhammadaamirali-and-nitin-bathija)

Comment: This is not using the Volley API

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with volley!